# Armature causing improper deformation of model

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I have a droid model as you can see in the image. I have parented the Droid to the bones but for some reason when I move the bones to animate the droid it stretches the mesh.

[image: model showing the incorrect deformation]

Answer (score 1):

I guess a part of the right side leg is influenced by the left side leg bones, you need to clear their influence in the weight paint mode.

select your right side leg (in object mode) then go in the weight paint mode (**ctrl+tab**)

[image]

right click on each bone to see it's influence on your object, when you click the left side leg bones you will see they are affecting the wrong object.

now you can fix that, hit **t** to show your brush tools, then select **subtract** in the blend drop menu, then paint your object to clear any influence of the left leg bones.

blue color means that the selected bone has no influence on the object.

[image]